# How do I dynamically update a fragment in a FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android

I'm writing a simple Fragment Activity with a FragmentPagerAdapter and two Fragments, where I need to show certain data in tab2 related to my selection in tab1. But the data in tab2 is never updated. Is there any common procedure for this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a common holder for data, Activity object is most suitable, since it is parent of both fragments. All fragments can use `getActivity()` in `onCreate()`. You can call a method of Activity object to get selected data. The other fragment can similarly, call a method of Activity object to set selected data.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just created one instance of each Tab and added an update() method on tab 2 which I called from Tab 1. I couldn't find a built in solution so I did it my way.